# Geo heat map(google) with large data

Tags: google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3, data-visualization, heatmap

I want to plot a **heat map** in **google map** to show the **taxi-ride distribution** of a city.

I got around **4000 data** of the taxi-ride starting location(latitude and longitude).

Here are some of my script:

First I set up the google map:

```
var hongkong = new google.maps.LatLng(22.28552,114.15769 );

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: hongkong,
    zoom: 11,
 });
```

Then, I read the data from JSON file and make a heat map:

```
jQuery.getJSON("data.json", function(data) {
    var heatmapData = [];
    jQuery.each(data, function(key, val) {
          heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(val.fromLocation.lat, val.fromLocation.lng));
    });

    var heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
          data: heatmapData
    });
    heatmap.setMap(map);
});
```

---

What I got:
[image]

You can see nothing. Then I zoom out, I got:

[image]

What I **expected** is something like this:
[image]

What is the problem? Is it the data I got is too close to each other?

Is there a better way to plot the heat map to show the distribution of taxi-riding? Thank you.

Comment: What does the contents of data.json look like?

Comment: `{ "fromLocation": {"lat": "22.37898", "lng": "114.108169"}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON file has got the latitudes and longitudes as strings.  Google's [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) constructor expects those values to be numbers.  Try this, which converts them from strings like `"22.37898"` to floats like `22.37898`

```
heatmapData.push(new google.maps.LatLng(
    parseFloat(val.fromLocation.lat), 
    parseFloat(val.fromLocation.lng))
);
```

Comment: After changing the code, I got the error msg: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NaN' of undefined visualization_impl.js:2`

Comment: That's a problem with your data then. What does `console.log(val)` inside your `.each` loop look like?

Comment: Ops, problem solved. I got some blank data inside. Thank you very much!